# Unexpect error with encoding website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web, webserver

I have an unexpected problem with some of my users, the website works correctly but sometimes the page can not display and it encoding

One of my users sent my a print screen of the error

[image]

the link of my website : http://bestyle.ps/aboutus.aspx

In global config I save all the errors in a database but this is not a programming error

so can you help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add athis to your html

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

UTF8 supports arabic characters